# Deployment of JSF Web Application fails on Tomcat 11 but works on Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, jsf, mojarra

During the deployment of my application in Netbeans the log says:

```
06-Mar-2024 20:23:39.783 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
jakarta.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
```

The application deploys correctly unter Tomcat 10. After reading the Tomcat 11 release information I thought the transition to would be easy.

My web.xml looks like this:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" 
         version="5.0" metadata-complete="true">
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>native</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_SUPPRESS</param-name>
        <param-value>java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException,java.nio.channels.IllegalSelectorException</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>dashboard/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/changes/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/finance/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/forecast/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/inventory/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/license/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/order/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/project/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/requests/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobimanager</role-name>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
            <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>

        </auth-constraint>
        
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobiadmin</role-name>

        </auth-constraint>
        
         <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/inventory/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobiappliances</role-name>

        </auth-constraint>
        
         <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/license/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobilicenses</role-name>

        </auth-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/order/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobiorder</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/shoppingcart/calculator.xhtml</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These roles are allowed access</description>
            <role-name>oobicalculator</role-name>    

        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
        
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ico</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
        
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mgdsrvoobm</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>jakarta.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                    
    </resource-ref>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
</web-app>
```

Maybe someone has the same problem and already found a solution for that. I searched already around the internet and couldn't find a solution.

This is the log:

```
07-Mar-2024 11:59:13.308 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-44] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/neptun]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
07-Mar-2024 11:59:13.814 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-44] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/neptun]
07-Mar-2024 11:59:13.832 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/Users/Michael/apache-tomcat-11.0.0-M17/conf/Catalina/localhost/neptun.xml]
07-Mar-2024 11:59:13.833 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/neptun] in deployment descriptor [/Users/Michael/apache-tomcat-11.0.0-M17/conf/Catalina/localhost/neptun.xml] has been ignored
07-Mar-2024 11:59:13.837 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Context/Realm] failed to set property [digest] to [MD5]
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobimanager] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [tomcat] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [manager-gui] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobiadmin] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobiappliances] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobilicenses] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobiorder] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.413 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [oobicalculator] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.433 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.439 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.448 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.<clinit> WELD-000900: 4.0.0 (Final)
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.542 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.676 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer.initialize WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.799 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra 4.0.0-M1 for context '/neptun'
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.847 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.996 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
    com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:316)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4409)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4844)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:711)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:599)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1667)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1477)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:619)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:716)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    Caused by: jakarta.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:202)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:660)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:349)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:384)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:217)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:307)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:200)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
        at com.sun.faces.config.manager.tasks.ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.initializeIvars(ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.config.manager.tasks.ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.getAnnotationScanURIs(ProvideMetadataToAnnotationScanTask.java:91)
        at com.sun.faces.config.manager.tasks.FindAnnotatedConfigClasses.call(FindAnnotatedConfigClasses.java:83)
        at com.sun.faces.config.manager.tasks.FindAnnotatedConfigClasses.call(FindAnnotatedConfigClasses.java:40)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.findAnnotations(ConfigManager.java:354)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:247)
        ... 43 more
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.999 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
07-Mar-2024 11:59:15.999 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/neptun] startup failed due to previous errors
07-Mar-2024 11:59:16.010 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/Users/Michael/apache-tomcat-11.0.0-M17/conf/Catalina/localhost/neptun.xml] has finished in [2,178] ms
```

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace. Please never ignore them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't unterstand why "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null. That makes it difficult for me to fix it. 

I thought the problem could be my Netbeans IDE because my Java EE Version is Jakarta EE 10 Web there and Tomcat 11 supports Jakarta EE 11 Web.

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace. You need to look up it in server logs and edit your question to include it. Then we can translate it for you in layman's terms. It are those lines starting with `at` and ending with source code line numbers which normally appears *after* the exception message. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788

Comment: Thank you for the information and help. I edited my post with the log from Tomcat 11

Comment: Ok, this is most likely a bug in Mojarra. But there are 2 things you definitely need to do: 1) remove the entire ConfigureListener entry from your web.xml, this is supposed to be automatic; 2) do NOT use milestone versions in production, you must upgrade Mojarra 4.0.0-M1 to latest available 4.0.x which is [currently](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces) 4.0.5. After upgrading, please retry to see if the problem isn't already fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The upgrade to Mojarra 4.0.5 fixed the problem and the application started without an error.